# android camera failure delivering result resultinfo

Tags: android, camera, android-activity, imageview

Ok, this is obviously a duplicate question but in all other I did not find solution that works...

So, I'm trying to take a picture with camera and show this image in imageview... For now, it's not important if it's efficient or anything so I'm not dealing with this...

Here is my code:

Run camera:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePicture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File image = null;
                try {
                    image = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    finish();
                }
                if(image != null) {
                    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

`createImageFile` method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String name = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + "";
    File dir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File image = File.createTempFile(name, ".png", dir);
    path = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

and `onActiviyResult` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        String path = data.getExtras().getString(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
        File f = new File(path);

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()), 50, 50, true);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Important thing to mention is that my app never reaches `onActivityResult` method but stuck somewhere after I take a picutre and click Save to save picture (this screen shows after image is taken, it not something I implemented but it's the way it is on Android)

Here is my logcat:

```
04-08 14:57:37.230    5976-5976/hr.fer.dummyproj E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {hr.fer.dummyproj/hr.fer.dummyproj.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hr.fer.dummyproj.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)  
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**
So, I found where was the problem. It looks like camera activity does not return anything in Intent if it's saving picture in file. So, in `onResultActivity`, data was null.
To make it work, I saved Uri and in `onResultActivity` get picutre with it

Comment: I hope [take picture using camera application tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) helps you...

Comment: and please paste your log entries...

Comment: Can you show us your working code? Also, @y.dixit I tried that tutorial, and using the exact code does not work for me.

Comment: @MrPablo can you please specify the exact problem that you are facing...

Comment: @y.dixit well I don't know exactly. Simply, I tried the official tutorial and it gives me an error.

Comment: @MrPablo Please post your code and error that you are getting, so that people can help you out to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me....

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
Button captureImageButton;
static ImageView imageCapturedView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_image);
captureImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

OnClickListener captureImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent captureImageIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(captureImageIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
        {
            File photoFile=null;

            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();

            }catch(IOException e){};

            if(photoFile != null)
            {

                captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

        }

    }
};

captureImageButton.setOnClickListener(captureImageListener);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
imageCapturedView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
{
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap= (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    imageCapturedView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    galleryAddPic();
    setPic();
}
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{

String TimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String ImageFile = "JPEG_" + TimeStamp + "_";
File StorageDir =   Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

File image = File.createTempFile(ImageFile, ".jpg", StorageDir); 

mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

return image;

}

private void galleryAddPic()
{
Intent mediaScan = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f= new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScan.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScan);

}


private void setPic() throws ArithmeticException{


int scaleFactor;
Bitmap bitmap;
// Get the dimensions of the View
int targetW = imageCapturedView.getWidth();
int targetH = imageCapturedView.getHeight();


// Get the dimensions of the bitmap
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

// Determine how much to scale down the image
    scaleFactor= Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

// Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;



bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
imageCapturedView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.take_image, menu);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, I wolud prefer if anyone can say why my code is not working (and I was doing it following official tutorial... Also, I forgot to mention that camera saves pictures in phone and I am able to show them in imageview after, but it does not return from camera activity in a proper way...

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you mean by "it does not return from camera activity in a proper way"

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my problem. I tought that problem was in returning from camera activity (cannot be more specific because that was not actual problem)... Read my update in first post for more details on where was the problem after all.